# Accessing File from tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Hello im trying to access and use a HTML file in a tomcat servlet from my InteliJ project folder .
I deploy the Intelij Porject with smart-tomcat.

In the project structure I have tried to put the html file in the root of the project(C/User/Empty/Projects/servlet) but it just doesn't go to the directory that tomcat uses and reads from (C:\Users\Empty.SmartTomcat\servlet\rest).

My question is how will I be able to move the file dynamically when I deploy it and accsess it from my code ? eg (new File("relative/path")) thats the same on project and when deployed on tomcat

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone can give some insightful info even though someone marked it as dupe would be extremely helpful

Comment: Your initial question was after all apparently badly formulated. I've fixed the dupe based on the changed question.

Comment: my bad, but holy that's not what I want either